# Trying to push a button to bottom of linear layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-button

I know this can be very easily done by using a Relative Layout but I feel what I am doing is correct and should give me the desired result with the Linear Layout itself. But for some reason, when I run on this on Google Nexus 7 running Android JB 4.1.2, I see the button and the text view immediately after the list view items. If the list view is empty, I see them at the top of the screen. Am I doing something wrong?? Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/attachments_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mtg_attachments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/attach_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/delete"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
<TextView
    android:text="@string/attach_warning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `android:weightSum` attribute from the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: As Ted Hopp suggested, I believe you should remove the weight sum attribute from the linear layout.

Comment: I tried removing the weightsum... Nothing happens with that... It remains the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center an item in the middle of the screen don't use a LinearLayout as these are meant for displaying a number of items in a row stacked one after another.

Use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead.

So replace:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

for the relevant `RelativeLayout` option:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: As I said, I know the Relative Layout would work and have already tried it.. But I generally use Linear Layouts across my apps and was just curious on why this wasnt giving me the desired results... So I cannot accept your solution though it works...

Comment: Looks like I have to finally go with the Relative Layout... Will wait to see if someone else comes up with something interesting....

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/attachments_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mtg_attachments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:gravity="bottom" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/attach_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="delete"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="attach_warning"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: While this may work, I dont want to specify any space for the button and textview. They should just take what they need at the bottom and the listview should occupy rest of the space.. So I dont think this is the solution...

Answer (score 2):

I know this question already have an accepted answer but I'm going to reply anyway since no solution was found and this is the first result google gave me about this problem I also had.

Just put a `LinearLayout (vertical)` with `layout:weight = 1` between the 2 elements you want to divide.

In your code, that would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/attachments_list"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:weightSum="1"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mtg_attachments"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <LinearLayout
        <!-- You should add this one and remove android:layout_weigth="1" form the listview -->
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/attach_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/delete"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/attach_warning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that the added LinearLayout needs to be the only one with the weight property set, otherwise we have to face some problem.

Comment: Not sure if this would work... The linear layout would take all the space and the listview would take none... I will try it when I get a chance...

Comment: It will start exactly like that. But a list view is meant to contain elements, and this listview will expand as the elements are inserted (you don't have to trust me, try it yourself). The only problem is, the button and the TextView will be at the bottom of the screen and, when the list will touch them, they'll be pushed down and they'd be unreachable, but you can wrap anything inside a ScrollView to avoid that :)

Comment: you're right! I was talking about the ListView as a general element, I didn't even though of it asa ListView. To make it clear, ListView and Scrollviews won't push your element out of the screen. Sorry for the confusion my previous post could have raised.

Answer (score 1):

Sriman please have a look at this answer and then tell me if this is useful.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/attachments_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mtg_attachments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/attach_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="delete"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="attach_warning"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But Sriman it is working fine on my end. if this is not your solution what you want please elaborate some more

Comment: Have you tried running it on a device or emulator.. The graphical layout on eclipse would look fine but it doesnt actually work the same way on the device. As I said, I am using a Google Nexus 7 with Jelly Bean 4.1.2. Your environment could be different...

Answer (score 0):

modify your xml code.

using the `android:layout_weight` to tune the percentage of your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/attachments_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mtg_attachments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/attach_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:text="@string/delete"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
<TextView
    android:text="@string/attach_warning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: While this may work, I dont want to specify any space for the button and textview. They should just take what they need at the bottom and the listview should occupy rest of the space.. So I dont think this is the solution...